# How to return a value (not an object) in Android from chaquopy python function

Tags: python, chaquopy

I have just started with java and I tried chaquopy in order to run some scripts in my android application. The thing is that when I call the function i need, it returns a value (user_input), but I can't figure out how to get that value in Android. I have look at the methods of PyObject and I haven't found the way to return the integer I need (df['y'][1]).

```
def realtime(user_input):

    #Libraries
    import datetime
    import requests
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import pandas_datareader as web

    #Get the data
    currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()
    end=str(currentDT.year)+'-'+str(currentDT.month)+'-'+str(currentDT.day)
    start=str(currentDT.year)+'-'+str(currentDT.month-1)+'-'+str(currentDT.day)

    df = web.DataReader(str(user_input), data_source='yahoo',start=start,end=end)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=df['Close'])
    df.columns=['y']
    df['ds']=df.index

    return(df['y'][1])
```

This is the function im calling in java.

```
public int getrtasset() {
        Python py = Python.getInstance();
        PyObject pyfile = py.getModule("getAssetValue");
        PyObject va = pyfile.callAttr("realtime", getMtitulo());

        return va
    }
```

And this is the java function. "getAssetValue" is the name of the **.py**. I want to return the integer of the python function, but can't find a method to get that returned value in the PyObject va.

Thanks in advance.

**Solved: It was a double.. PyObject.toDouble() solved it.**

Comment: A quick look at the chaquopy docs indicates that you'd just need to call `.toInt()` on your PyObject (or perhaps `.toLong()` if it might not fit in 32 bits).

Comment: I have already tried that, but the thing is that, as it is an object, it can't convert it. The error it return is: **java.lang.ClassCastException: TypeError: Cannot convert float64 object to java.lang.Long**

Comment: It's not actually an int, then.  Try `.toDouble()`.

Comment: Oh, that was my fault, silly thing. Thank very much.